# parsing url in bbcode

Tags: php, regex, parsing, url, bbcode

Hi I'm developing a custom forum on my website. I would like to convert the urls starting with : http://*.domain.com/photos/{username}/{photo_id} (I should get both username and photo_id ) to the direct image tag so that user get the image instead of the url.

This should be done if they insert the url with or without bbcode:
ie:
http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345
[url=http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345]my photo link here[/url]
[url=http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345]http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345[/url]

This should be converted to < html-imge tag src="url-to_photo-path/photo_id.j_p_g" />

I tried this:

```
$str = "http://www.domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345"
$str = preg_replace_callback("'\[url=http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/photos\/(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]'i", 'self::parse_photo_url', $str);

 AND 

   $str = preg_replace_callback("#^https?://([a-z0-9-]+\.)domain.com/photos/(.*?)$#", 'self::parse_gpp_photo', $str);



 function parse_photo_url($url){
{

        $full_url = "http://www.domain.com/" . $url[1];
        $url_segs = parse_url($full_url);
        $path = explode("/", $url_segs['path']);
        return '<img src="http://www.domain.com/{path-to-the-gallery}/'.$path[2].'/jpg" />';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Musthafa.

I'm not sure that I've exactly got what you want but please try this:

```
<?php

$image_url_samples = array(
    "http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345",
    "[url=http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345]my photo link here[/url]",
    "[url=http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345]http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345[/url]"
);

foreach ($image_url_samples as $image_url_sample)
{
    $conversion_result = preg_replace("/^(http:\\/\\/domain.com\\/photos\\/\\w+\\/\\d+)$/i",
        "<img src=\"\\1.jpg\" alt=\"\\1\" />", $image_url_sample);
    $conversion_result = preg_replace("/^\\[url=(http:\\/\\/domain.com\\/photos\\/\\w+\\/\\d+)\\](.+)\\[\\/url\\]$/",
        "<img src=\"\\1.jpg\" alt=\"\\2\" />", $conversion_result);
    print $conversion_result . "<br />";
}
```

The output is:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345.jpg" alt="http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345" />
<br />
<img src="http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345.jpg" alt="my photo link here" />
<br />
<img src="http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345.jpg" alt="http://domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345" />
<br />
```

By the way, if you want to make your URL case insensitive add the `i` modifier to the end of regular pattern ([PHP Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would like to extract the id (12345 in this example) and I need to extract the direct link to the image url so that, user should get the image tag instead of url.

Thats why I called

```
preg_replace_callback function.
```

In simple words, I'm stuck at the regex pattern to match my domain url starting with:

```
http://domain.com/photos{username}/{id} 
OR
http://www.domain.com/photos{username}/{id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex.

```
function buildLink( $id, $name ){

  $html   = array();
  $html[] = '<img alt="" src="http://www.domain.com/photos/';
  $html[] = $name;
  $html[] = '/';
  $html[] = $id;
  $html[] = '.jpg">';

  return implode( '', $html );

}

$path       = 'http://www.domain.com/photos/musthafa/12345';
$path       = rtrim( $path, ' /' );
$path_parts = explode( '/', $path );
$id         = ( int ) array_pop( $path_parts );
$name       = array_pop( $path_parts );
$img        = buildLink( $id, $name );
echo $img;
```